# Using Shields with Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: sms, gsm, raspberry-pi2

I want to use an RPI2 for SMS messaging. I got a Raspberry Pi Itead SIM800 GSM/GPRS V2 [Link Here](http://wiki.iteadstudio.com/RPI_SIM800_GSM/GPRS_ADD-ON_V2.0)

Where do I begin using shields? Is it as simple as setting the shield into the pins on the RPI2? Do I have to program the GPIO pins in some manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, you pop it on to your Raspberry Pi 2, and you communicate with it via serial interface, like you'd normally do. An example can be found [here](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/SerialSample). Very informative article with useful links on how to [set-up the software part](http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/GetStarted.htm) of your Raspberry Pi can be found [here](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/SerialSample.htm). You have to use the AT commands described in the manual linked at the bottom of [the page](http://wiki.iteadstudio.com/RPI_SIM800_GSM/GPRS_ADD-ON_V2.0) you mention in your question. GPIO is not really required unless you want to power-on/power-off or reset your add-on programmatically.

I got mine yesterday in the mail, and got the basics working just in a few hours.